# Java 8 Stream in main method

Tags: stream, java-8

Someone asked me in an interview if we shoul write streaming operation in the main method.

Does it makes any difference?

For example:

```
class Athlete {

  private String name;
  private int id;

  public Athlete(String  name,int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }
}

public class Trial {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Athlete> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Athlete("John", 1));
    list.add(new Athlete("Jim", 2));
    list.add(new Athlete("Jojo", 3));

    list.stream().forEach(System.out::print); // or any other any stream operation
  }
}
```

So I am just curious to know if it makes any difference... For now, the only thing I know is that once the stream is consumed, it cannot be consumed again.

So does it affect the memory or create buffer memory in the JVM for streaming?

If yes? Why should this not be used in the main method?

Comment: I don't think there is anything about streams which make them special with regards to main method/thread. Whatever arguments you can use pro or against could be as well used for using Iterators or any other loops.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.....its just an example....i am not asking  about loops here...i am asking about writing any stream operation inside our main method.... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question whether “we should write streaming operation in the main method” is a loaded question. The first thing it implies, is the assumption that there was something special about the `main` method. Regardless of which operations we are talking about, if the conclusion is that you may or may not use them in an arbitrary method, there is no reason why you should come to a different conclusion when the method in question is the `main` method.

Apparently, “should we …” is meant to actually ask whether “should we avoid …”. If that’s the question, then, keeping in mind that there are no special rules for the `main` method, if there was a reason forbidding the use of the Stream API, that reason also applied to all other methods, making the Stream API an unusable API. Of course, the answer is that there is no reason forbidding the Stream API in the `main` method.

---

Regarding memory consumption, when replacing a for-each loop with a `Collection.forEach` method invocation, you are trading an `Iterator` instance for a lambda instance, so have no signifcant difference in the number and size of the created object instances. If you use Stream’s `forEach` method, you add a `Spliterator` and a `Stream` instance, which still can be considered insignificant, even when your application consists of the `main` method only. The memory pre-allocated by a JVM is much larger than the memory consumed by those few objects and your objects are very likely to fit within the threads’s local allocation store. In other words, from the outside of the JVM, there will be no difference in the memory used by the process.

As you mentioned the term “buffer”, the conceptual thing you *should* know is that a Stream does *not* buffer elements for most operations (including `forEach`), so, regardless of whether you traverse a Collection via loop or Stream, in both cases no memory scaling with the Collection’s size is ever allocated, so the difference, if any, remains as small as described above, regardless of whether you iterate over three elements as in your example or over three million elements.

---

On issue that could create confusion is that you should not use multi-threaded operations in a class initializer, which implies that you should not use a *parallel* stream in a class initializer. But that’s not forbidding Stream operations per se, further, the `main` method is not a class initializer; when the `main` method is invoked, the class has been initialized already.

Comment: *"when replacing a for-each loop with a Collection.forEach method invocation, you are trading an Iterator instance for a lambda instance"*... You mean a `Iterable.forEach` ? Or there is something that I misunderstood... anyway +1.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: yes, `forEach` is defined in `Iterable`, but that `default` implementation uses an `Iterator` whereas most Collections, most notably `ArrayList`, take the opportunity to provide an optimized `forEach` implementation, which iterates without creating an `Iterator` instance. That’s the scenario to consider like, e.g. in the question’s code. While thinking of this scenario, I simply forgot that `forEach` is not only a Collection method, but also defined in the more abstract `Iterable` interface.

Answer (score 2):

In interview questions, don't assume that every yes/no question is limited to those two choices. A good answer might be "no difference either way".

In this case, they might have been looking for you to recognize that `list.foreach()` is more efficient than `list.stream().foreach()`.

Comment: hi hank...looping was just an example....in real case i mean in interview i was writing something else like this list.stream().filter(something which returns boolean).
So the only thing was..... is it right to write stream in main()?